# How to use coupons with Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, cloudpagesurl

In researching alternatives to the soon to be deprecated Class Email Live Offers/Coupons, I'm looking into Marketing Cloud - CloudPages.

I am looking for a way to send coupons via email to an audience, however, if I am not mistaken, based on details found [here](https://www.dummies.com/business/marketing/create-content-marketing-clouds-cloudpages/), it appears that only the following template types are available:

- Landing Page
- Code Resource
- Microsite
- MobilePush page
- Facebook Tab

With a template selected, I see that *coupons* is a content type to integrate.

I don't see email template.  Is this feature available through Email Studio and if so, can someone please direct me to reading sources in creating or integrating a db of coupon codes/

Comment: Hey EliHaix, where will the Coupon Codes come from - will they come from a fixed list of codes, or will you need to generate new codes in real time (via API, or other)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put Coupon Codes in a Data Extension and use Ampscript with the functino "ClaimRow"  when you use them. You can also use expiration dates and stuff like that if you are building something more sophisticated. You can put that code inside an email as an HTML Block for instance.
Have a look here: 
[Send a coupon - Claim row](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199828/send-a-coupon-claim-row)

Comment: At first glance, this may be what I'm looking for.  In classic, the system retired used coupons, did tracking, etc.  Are those features still available under the new context?

Comment: What we did was, that we updated the row we used with the subscriberkey and a time stamp. First of all, that will give you the security of displaying the same coupon code in webview then in the actual newsletter. Secondly you would be able to see when which coupon was taken. If you need some sort of warning when you are running low on coupons, you could build an automation that checks for unused coupons regularly and then sends you a message.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Isn't this the functionality that Live Offers and Live Coupons has, which is being deprecated?  If so, wondering why there isn't a more out-of-the-box solution.